# How to prevent \xspace from adding a full space after a period?

Tags: spacing, punctuation, xspace

I have a little macro that I use for doing adding an *e.g.* in my writing:

```
\newcommand{\eg}{\emph{e.g.}\xspace}
```

The problem I have is that LaTeX is treating the `g.` as the end of a sentence and is spacing too much. Is there any way to disable this feature?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `\@` to the definition of your custom macro. See [When should I use intersentence spacing (`\@')?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55105/when-should-i-use-intersentence-spacing) for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\origeg}{\emph{e.g.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\eg}{\emph{e.g.}\@\xspace}

\begin{document}

Some text \origeg and some more

Some text \eg and some more

\end{document}
```

[image]