# \@ vs. \␣ after abbreviation. (Read backslash-at vs. backslash-space)

Tags: spacing, punctuation

I was used to write abbreviations like `foo i.e.\ bar` but today learned that I could also write them as `foo i.e.\@ bar`. Both of these apparently have the effect of keeping the space to its normal inter-word size, as opposed to the larger after-sentence space. The fact that there are two possible ways to express what appears to me the same thing makes me wonder whether I might be missing some part of the picture here.

**Is there any reason to prefer one of these over the other?
When should I use which?**

Unfortunately I haven't found much authoritative documenation about either of these. The [latex2e reference manual](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/%2acheckout%2a/latexrefman/trunk/latex2e.html#g_t_005cSPACE) describes the use of `\@` *before* the period, but not its use after a period. The Advanced TeXbook doesn't mention `\@` in its index, which might be considered an indication that it's a LaTeX addition. Various questions, answers and comments on this site here mention one, the other or even both, but so far I haven't found a clear rule about when to use which.

So far I'd tend to keep using `\␣` in preference to `\@`, because I find it easier to read and because that use is better represented in documentation.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55105/5049

Comment: `\@` works even if you don't have a space. There's really no reason for preferring one to the other.

Comment: `\@` isn't defined in `plain.tex`, only in latex.  if you use it, just be careful where you put it -- the two meanings give diametrically opposite results.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are putting them explicitly in the document, then it doesn't really matter. If you are making a macro it's better to use `\@` form.

```
\newcommand\zzz{i.e.\@}
\newcommand\yyy{i.e.\ }
\newcomamnd\xxx{i.e.}
```

with `\zzz` you can use `\zzz\ jjj` or `\zzz{} jjj` and you get the correct spacing. With `\yyy` the spacing is forced (so it is not so good if you don't want any space at all as in `\yyy, bbbbb` ) and in `\xxx` you need to know the command ends with a non-sentence `.` so follow it with `\` or `\@`  not `{}`.

Comment: Is it possible to make this more robust with `xspace`?

Comment: @SeanAllred, see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620  :-)

Comment: @SeanAllred See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15009/21591