# Inter-sentence space without a period?

Tags: spacing

How can I insert an inter-sentence space without using a period?

I can easily get an inter-word space via `\␣` (backslash followed by a space), or `~` if I don't want line breaking.  Is there something equivalent for inter-sentence space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the space factor to the space factor code of the period.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\intersentencespace}{\spacefactor\sfcode`. \space}

\begin{document}

Ends.\ Here.

Ends. Here.

.Ends\intersentencespace Here.

\bigskip

\xspaceskip=30pt

Ends.\ Here.

Ends. Here.

.Ends\intersentencespace Here.

\end{document}
```

The strange code `.Ends\intersentencespace Here` is for getting the same width before the space.

In the first three lines, the normal spacing is considered. In the second part, an artificially enlarged `\xspacskip` clearly shows the effect.

[image]

Comment: How do I get this to work after a capital letter?  I'm worried that adding `\@` to the beginning of the definition of `\intersentencespace` would [interfere with kerning](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55105/when-should-i-use-intersentence-spacing/55112#comment115440_55112) and [italic correction](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55105/when-should-i-use-intersentence-spacing/55112#comment117772_55112).

Comment: @RichardHansen It *does* work after capital letters, with no change.

Comment: Oops, you're right—I made a mistake in my test document.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own command, by adding `fontdimen2` (interword space) to `fontdimen7` (extra space). See section 4.3.1 of [TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) .

```
\documentclass{article}
\newdimen\mydimen
\mydimen=\fontdimen2\font
\advance\mydimen by \fontdimen7\font
\newcommand\sspc{\hskip\mydimen}
\begin{document}
\noindent
test. test\\
test\sspc{}test\\
test test
\end{document}
```

[image]